# How can I preserve columns' sorting in DataGrid after changing its ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How can I preserve columns' sorting in `DataGrid` after changing its `ItemsSource`?

The following code preserve sorting but it doesn't set column headers of `DataGrid` to the "sorted" state (so there's no "sorting" icon and that stuff):

```
SortDescriptionCollection sortDescriptions = new SortDescriptionCollection();
foreach (SortDescription sd in OccupationsDataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions)
{
    sortDescriptions.Add(sd);
}

OccupationsDataGrid.ItemsSource = q;

foreach (SortDescription sd in sortDescriptions)
{
    OccupationsDataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Telerik's JustDecompile and looking at the DataGrid.

In the static constructor for DataGrid, we have this line:

```
ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty.OverrideMetadata(type, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new CoerceValueCallback(DataGrid.OnCoerceItemsSourceProperty)));
```

So DataGrid.OnCoerceItemsSourceProperty is called when the ItemsSource changes. It is defined as this:

```
private static object OnCoerceItemsSourceProperty(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)d;
    if (baseValue != dataGrid._cachedItemsSource && dataGrid._cachedItemsSource != null)
    {
        dataGrid.ClearSortDescriptionsOnItemsSourceChange();
    }
    return baseValue;
}
```

It ends up calling ClearSortDescriptionsOnItemsSourceChange. Which is this:

```
private void ClearSortDescriptionsOnItemsSourceChange()
{
    base.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    this._sortingStarted = false;
    List<int> groupingSortDescriptionIndices = this.GroupingSortDescriptionIndices;
    if (groupingSortDescriptionIndices != null)
    {
        groupingSortDescriptionIndices.Clear();
    }
    foreach (DataGridColumn column in this.Columns)
    {
        column.SortDirection = null;
    }
}
```

It appears that the column's SortDirection is being wiped out and that must control the appearance of the sort arrows. So... we should put it back when we add our sort descriptions back. Change the loop that re-adds the SortDescriptions to this:

```
foreach (SortDescription sd in sortDescriptions)
{
    OccupationsDataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
    foreach (var col in OccupationsDataGrid.Columns.Where(aa => aa.SortMemberPath == sd.PropertyName))
    {
        col.SortDirection = sd.Direction;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with a similar issue when changing ItemsSource, it breaks sort descriptions for the new ItemsSource, and just defaults back to the default sorting.

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    static CustomDataGrid()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomDataGrid)));

        // Override Coerce of ItemsSourceProperty 
        ItemsSourceProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnCoercItemsSource));
    }

    private static object OnCoercItemsSource(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
    {
        // DataGrid messes up sorting changing the ItemsSource. Overriding this method
        // to do nothing fixes that issue, and keeps column sorting intact when changing ItemsSource.
        return basevalue;
    }
}
```

The following code fixes issue where sorting breaks, and it also retains current column sort of the datagrid.